# PHP table of contents HTML

Tags: php

I have got a php file which uses an `include` function to import the article. The article is a php file. I would like to create a `table_of_contents()` function, which I place inside the file where I want a contents list to appear (like on Wikipedia articles). This function should scan the article for all `<h2>` tags with IDs beginning with "`article-`", and output a list of these headings as links.

Eg:

```
<h1>Article</h1>
<?php table_of_contents() ?>
<h2 id="article-intro">Introduction</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2>Middle</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2 id="article-conclusion">Conclusion</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

would render

```
<h1>Article</h1>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#article-intro">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#article-conclusion">Conclusion</a></li>
</ul>
<h2 id="article-intro">Introduction</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2>Middle</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2 id="article-conclusion">Conclusion</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: and what have *you* tried?

Comment: A hint: `preg_match_all`. Just try yourself first!

Comment: you should be better off with either a static site generator or a database holding datas of your website. You are going the hardest way with that method. and it wont scale. There is a big flaw in your method. the function table_of_contents needs to know all the h2 before it is executed, how can it be if the h2 are declared after the function call ?

Comment: @sebastian, thanks. I'll try something like `/<h2\s+[^>]id="article\-(\w+)">([\w ]+)<\/h2>/` How do I get the string of the page, though?

Comment: Have you looked at http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php ? There you will find your answer. And maybe you just need `<h2 id="article\-(.+)">(.+)<\/h2>`, that also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h1>Article</h1>
<ul Id="menu">

</ul>
<h2 id="article-intro">Introduction</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2>Middle</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2 id="article-conclusion">Conclusion</h2>
<p>text</p>


<script>
$('h2[id^="article-"]').each(function(){
$('#menu').append('<li><a href="#article-'+$(this).html()+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a></li>');
});
</script>
```

I think this will work. Don't forget to include the latest jquery.

Comment: I was going to submit the same strategy. One point of concern, I think you need to lowercast the html() in href, or just use href=#"'+$this.id instead